# KDL parser: URDF parsing issue

Tags: urdf, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

This question seems a bit obvious/easy but I am not able to get the KDL parser working with URDF file for making a KDL tree. I am following [this](https://wiki.ros.org/kdl_parser/Tutorials/Start%20using%20the%20KDL%20parser) tutorial, section 2.1 - KDL parser: From a file. I am not able to pass the correct *filename* in the function `kdl_parser::treeFromFile("filename", tree)`. I tried with the model urdf name, the relative path to that file, the absolute path; all of them gives the same error while running - **Error document empty.** Can anyone specify how to pass the URDF file to the function?

ROS: Melodic

**Edit:**
As mentioned by @pmuthu2s in the comment, I added below line in the launch file.

```
<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find exercise2)/model/robots/sim.urdf"/>
```

Also the code for parsing looks like this:

```
KDL::Tree lumi_tree;
std::string lumi_robot;
node.param("robot_description", lumi_robot, std::string());
if (!kdl_parser::treeFromFile(lumi_robot, lumi_tree)){
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to construct kdl tree");
    return false;
}
```

Still getting the same error. Probably I am doing something wrong here. Anyone know how to fix this?

Regards, 
Anand

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342967/kdl-parser:-urdf-parsing-issue/) by [AnandGeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/23126/anandgeorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2020-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2020-01-31**:
Hey,
Maybe check this out  [Error document empty](https://answers.ros.org/question/284693/canopen_motor_node-error-document-empty/)

**Comment by [AnandGeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/23126/anandgeorge/) on 2020-01-31**:
Added some more details in the question. Still the same error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-31**:
Have you checked whether `lumi_robot` actually contains anything?

And does `cat $(rospack find exercise2)/model/robots/sim.urdf` show the expected content?

**Comment by [AnandGeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/23126/anandgeorge/) on 2020-01-31**:
@gvdhoorn - I can see the urdf with that `cat` command. But the problem here is `lumi_robot` does not have any value. Thanks for pointing out that. The launch file just launches the robot and starts rviz. I run the executable separately. Is that the reason why it cannot get the URDF from rosparams? I am able to see the URDF with `rosparam get /robot_description`. I am getting the URDF as `std::string lumi_robot; node.param("robot_description", lumi_robot, std::string());`

**Comment by [AnandGeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/23126/anandgeorge/) on 2020-01-31**:
I changed the it to `/robot_description` as  `node.param("/robot_description", lumi_robot, std::string());`. Now `lumi_robot` as the content of `sim.urdf`. Still I am geting *Error document empty*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned in the question, I was trying to get the KDL tree of the robot by loading the URDF using `treeFromFile()` function with taking the URDF from the params server. I changed it to `treeFromString()` as the URDF is stored as a string after getting it from the params server. Below is the modified code.

```
KDL::Tree lumi_tree;
std::string lumi_robot;
node.param("/robot_description", lumi_robot, std::string());
if (!kdl_parser::treeFromString(lumi_robot, lumi_tree)){
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to construct kdl tree");
    return false;
}
```

Now the KDL tree is formed and is used for further calculations.

Thanks @pmuthu2s and @gvdhoorn for their inputs.

---

Originally posted by [AnandGeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/23126/anandgeorge/) with karma: 56 on 2020-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2020-02-03**:
No problem